# Test-Driven Development, Java, stuck with an assertion error

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

I was given a test suite for a test-driven development assignment. the program plays a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors and I was also given a skeletal code for the actual program. I am not supposed to change the test suite, but instead, I have to change, or make the code in the actual program so that the tests pass. I am having problem in the getting past the getInput method. 
This is the code for the actual program:

```
   public static char getInput(String prompt, char[] options, Scanner sc) {
 // getInput method
 // prompts user for an input that matches one of the given characters
 // if its not one of those, repeat. (use contains (above))
 char c;
 boolean flag = false;
 do {
   c = sc.next().charAt(0);
   if (contains(c, options)) {
     System.out.println(prompt + " ( y, n, q ):");
     flag = true;
   }
 }
 while (!flag);
return c; 
}
```

This is the method in the test suite to test the getInput method:`

```
    private static void testGetInput() {
    OutputStream out;

out = resetSystemOut();
assert 'y' == RPS.getInput("Choose", new char[] {'y','n','q'}, new Scanner("y\n"));
assertOutput("Choose ( y, n, q ):\n", out);
out = resetSystemOut();
assert 'n' == RPS.getInput("Alice", new char[] {'y','n','q'}, new Scanner("n\n"));
assertOutput("Alice ( y, n, q ):\n", out);
out = resetSystemOut();
assert 'q' == RPS.getInput("Bob", new char[] {'y','n','q'}, new Scanner("q\n"));
assertOutput("Bob ( y, n, q ):\n", out);
out = resetSystemOut();
assert 'q' == RPS.getInput("Cloe", new char[] {'y','n','q'}, new Scanner("x\nw\nq\n")); //line 81
assertOutput("Cloe ( y, n, q ):\n" +
    "Cloe ( y, n, q ):\n" +
    "Cloe ( y, n, q ):\n", out);
out = resetSystemOut();
assert 'v' == RPS.getInput("Doug", new char[] {'v'}, new Scanner("vvvv\nv\n"));
assertOutput("Doug ( v ):\n" +
    "Doug ( v ):\n", out);
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 54 18
Cloe ( y, n, q ):
Cloe ( y, n, q ):
Cloe ( y, n, q ):
Cloe ( y, n, q ):

        at RPSTester.assertOutput(RPSTester.java:226)
        at RPSTester.testGetInput(RPSTester.java:81)
        at RPSTester.main(RPSTester.java:25) //line 25 has a call to the testGetInput method
```

I've visited the instructor during office hours but there's only so much he can tell me before revealing the whole answer to the question. I would appreciate any help, hints, pointers to my mistakes; anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the print statement by concatenating the prompt and the characters from options and then print that statement as many number of times as the characters in the Scanner input. You may have to adjust the appending of new line character \n to match your test assertions.

This should help:

```
public static char getInput(String prompt, char[] options, Scanner sc) {
        // getInput method
        // prompts user for an input that matches one of the given characters
        // if its not one of those, repeat. (use contains (above))
        char c;
        boolean flag = false;
        String printStr = prompt + " (";
        for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            printStr += " " + options[i] + ",";
        }
        printStr = printStr.substring(0, printStr.length() - 1) + " ):\\n";

        do {
            c = sc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(printStr);
            if (contains(c, options)) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        while (!flag);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the test suite, but i have to change the code in the getInput method to make the assertions in the test suite pass

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
 while(scanner.hasNext()) {
   String input = scanner.next();
   //check if input equals to y or n or q . If yes then break
   // otherwise System.out.println(prompt + " ( y, n, q ):")  
 }
```

Comment: but if i do that, the fifth assert statement, which has the prompt "Doug" will fail because the expected the output is "Doug ( v ):" and we will get the output: "Doug ( y, n, q ):"

Comment: why is the output for "Doug (v)" is "Doug(v)" ? Is v a valid input?

Comment: yes, v is a valid input because that is what is being passed as an argument in the fifth assert statement in the given code. The array of the options is being created at each assertion test but for the first four tests it just happens to be the same.